# ASP.NET: Change the CSS link href in code hehind?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have an .ASPX page in which I want to change the CSS href in code behind. I searched for several tricks to do this but couldn't find anything that works as I intend.

**HTML Markup:**

```
<link id="linkCSS" runat="server" href='/css/1.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This is what I attempted in **Code behind:**

```
If (mobile)
{
    HtmlLink link = (HtmlLink)this.FindControl(linkCSS.UniqueID);
    link.Href = "/css/2.css";
}
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink'.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried: `HtmlLink link = (HtmlLink)linkCSS;`

Comment: @Emad Yes, same error

Comment: The error tells you everything you need to know. Your `<link>` tag is a Generic Html Contol, not a HtmlLink Control. For more info on how to use the HtmlLink control see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmllink(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to find css you can change it as follows.

```
If (mobile)
{
  linkCSS.Attributes["href"] = "~/css/2.css";
}
```

I've had reffered [This Link.](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-change-switch-CSS-file-programmatically-from-code-behind-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't get and modify the control (although I believe it's possible) you can use placeholder to have more control over it. Like this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="headPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
```

And then in your server code:

```
HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
link.Href = "/css/2.css";
headPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(link);
```

See if it helps :)

Comment: I am upvoting this because it works, but I will accept Chirag's solution since it's more elegant. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Very nice of you. Thanks for the help again.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code on your server side

```
HtmlGenericControl link = this.FindControl(linkCSS.UniqueID) as HtmlGenericControl;

link.Attributes["href"] = "css/2.css";
```

Comment: This is not significantly different from the accepted answer.